# Explanation of mixed product of tensors using basis vectors

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, tensors, kronecker-product

I cannot understand the mixed product
$$
(A\otimes B) (C\otimes D) = (AC) \otimes (BD)
$$

I try to follow from the bases:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(A\otimes B \right) \left(C \otimes D \right) &=& 
A_{ij}B_{kl}C_{mn}D_{pr}\ (e_i\otimes e_j \otimes e_k \otimes e_l) \ (e_m \otimes e_n \otimes e_p \otimes e_r) \\ 
&=& A_{ij}B_{kl}C_{mn}D_{pr}\ \delta_{lm} (e_i\otimes e_j \otimes e_k  \otimes e_n \otimes e_p\otimes e_r)  \\
&=& A_{ij}B_{kl}C_{ln}D_{pr}\ (e_i\otimes e_j \otimes e_k  \otimes e_n \otimes e_p\otimes e_r) 
\end{eqnarray}
$$
which is not equal to the correct one:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
(AC) \otimes (BD) &=& (A_{ij} C_{mn}\ e_i \otimes e_j\ e_m \otimes e_n) \otimes (B_{kl} D_{pr}\ e_k \otimes e_l\ e_p \otimes e_r) \\
&=& (A_{ij} C_{mn} \delta_{jm}\ e_i \otimes e_n) \otimes  (B_{kl} D_{pr} \delta_{lp} \ e_k \otimes e_r) \\
&=& (A_{ij} C_{jn} \ e_i \otimes e_n) \otimes  (B_{kl} D_{lr} \ e_k \otimes e_r) \\
&=& A_{ij} C_{jn} B_{kl} D_{lr} \ e_i \otimes e_n \otimes  \ e_k \otimes e_r
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Could you please help?

Comment: See paragraph "Mixed products" [here](https://www.statlect.com/matrix-algebra/Kronecker-product-properties) in the framework of/interpretation by Kronecker product.

Comment: Hey, thank you for suggestion. I kind of understand the explanation there. However, when I was taught continuum mechanics the lecturer was always using index notation explaining with mathematical interaction of bases. Now, I am not continuing to work with such math, but occasionally encounter them. So, I am rather after linking any tensor stuff back to how I learned it back then. Best.

Comment: You're using $\otimes$ to refer to two distinct operations. On the one hand, it denotes the Kronecker product, on the other it denotes an [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product)

Comment: Hi Ben Grossmann. Thank you. This solves my confusion mostly. Is there a bases representation of the Kronecker product then?